# How to remove white space at the bottom of matplotlib graph?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I looked over the matplotlib user guide and cant seem to find a way to remove the white space that is generated at the bottom of my graph.

```
fig = plt.figure(1,figsize=(5,10))
axis = fig.add_subplot(211, autoscale_on=False,xlim=(1,10),ylim=(0,1))
```

Are the configurations I am using on the graph.  I tried using frameon=False, but didnt notice it do anything.  I would like the graph to take up the entire size of the output image.

Here is the photo:
[image: Notice that half the graph is half white space at the bottom.]

I want to remove all this white space.  Both the answers provided do not do this... am I missing something else?

Comment: It would be helpful to see an image of what exactly you are talking about....

Comment: I can just agree with @mshell_lauren. Try to upload a picture that everybody can understand your problem. Maybe you should check the [subplot adjust](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.subplots_adjust).

Comment: I added photo. I tried adjust, but it didnt modify the photo.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're creating space for a second plot and not using it. The line

```
axis = fig.add_subplot(211, autoscale_on=False,xlim=(1,10),ylim=(0,1))
```

adds a subplot to the figure, but the `211` means "two plots high by one plot wide, position 1". You could add a second plot below your current one with another subplot call, passing `212' (position 2).

To create a single subplot and fix your issue, change your `add_subplot` call to:

```
axis = fig.add_subplot(111, autoscale_on=False,xlim=(1,10),ylim=(0,1))
```

The `111` meaning one by one plots, first position.

Answer (score 7):

If you are saving the output to a file, you could use `bbox_inches='tight'`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
fig=plt.figure(1,figsize=(5,10))
axis = fig.add_subplot(211, autoscale_on=False, xlim=(1,10), ylim=(0,1))
N=100
x = np.linspace(1,10, N)
y = np.cumsum(np.random.random(N)-0.5)
y -= y.min()
y /= y.max()
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.savefig('test.png', bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0.0)
```

Comment: I found that this causes an interesting error in the Python 3 version of matplotlib wherein the list display `ia_list = [a for k, a in self._elements)]` within the bbox code raises an exception along the lines of "expected `str` but received `bytes`". Never was able to figure out where the problem originated, but was able to resolve it by using `ia_list = dict(self._elements).values()` instead (with a few other changes in the surrounding lines of code to make the change transparent).

Comment: There is also the 'pad_inches' keyword, set to 0.1 by default.  Setting this to zero will further reduce padding.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not pretty sure what do you mean. If you want to control the position and the size of your subplot, try to use [add_axes( [left, bottom, width, height] )](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.add_axes). Following is a sample code, I set the boundary black to make sure you see it clearly:

```python
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6, 2.5))
ax = fig.add_axes([0.1, 0.18, 0.86, 0.75])

ax.plot([1, 2, 3, 9, 10], [0.85, 0.6, 0.5, 0.3, 0.32], 'b--', linewidth=2, label='Single Path')
ax.plot([1, 2, 3, 9, 10], [1, 0.6, 0.5, 0.27, 0.3], 'r:', linewidth=2, label='QoS First')

ax.legend(fancybox=True, shadow=True)
ax.set_xlabel('Simulations: Flows per Second Varying')
ax.set_ylabel('ACAR')
ax.axis([1, 10, 0, 1]) 
ax.grid()
plt.savefig('rm_wspace.png', edgecolor='k', dpi=300)
```

[image: rm_wsapce.png]

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use the subplots_adjust() function. I have found that,

fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.06)

seems to work best for me. This leaves just enough space at the bottom for tickmarks and an axis label. If you are wanting the graph to take up the entire output, simply set bottom to a smaller number.

Side note: subplots_adjust() can also control the white space on the top, left, and right as well as the spacing between subplots. Coordinates are units of the entire figure. That is, (0,0) is the bottom left and (1,1) is the top left.

Comment: I saw this solution on another post, but it didnt work.  It looks the exact same.  I added "fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.06)" right before I set "axis =fig.add_subplot(211, autoscale_on=False,xlim=(1,10),ylim=(0,1))"

Answer (score 0):

I usually remove all whitespace in my figures by removing the frame surrounding the graph. This is done using the `frameon=False` command defined [here](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/figure_api.html).

```
fig = plt.figure(1,figsize=(5,10),frameon=False)
axis = fig.add_subplot(211, autoscale_on=False,xlim=(1,10),ylim=(0,1))
```